# @JSGlobalScope in scala.js 1.0 (JavaScriptException, ReferenceError, var is not defined)

Tags: scala, scala.js

After migrating from scala.js `0.6.x` to `1.0`, I've got some code related to `@JSGlobalScope` broken.

My use case is like this:

- there's a 3rd-party library that expects some global var to be set to a function
- when loaded and ready, it calls this function (by name)
- I set this function in global scope from scala.js

The code looks like this:

```scala
  @js.native
  @JSGlobalScope
  object Globals extends js.Object {
    var callbackFunctionFor3rdPartyLib: js.Function0[Unit] = js.native
  }
```

then I set this var like this:

```
Globals.callbackFunctionFor3rdPartyLib = () => {
   // do things
}
```

and then I add the script into the DOM.

This was working with scala.js `0.6.x`, but with `1.0` I'm getting an exception like the following:

```
scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: ReferenceError: callbackFunctionFor3rdPartyLib is not defined
```

In the [changelog for 1.0.0](http://www.scala-js.org/news/2020/02/25/announcing-scalajs-1.0.0/) there's a "Breaking changes" section that mentions this:

> Accessing a member that is not declared causes a ReferenceError to be thrown
>   ...
>
> ```
> js.Dynamic.global.globalVarThatDoesNotExist = 42
> ```
>
> would previously create said global variable. In Scala.js 1.x, it also throws a ReferenceError.

My question is:

what is the right way to do something like this (create a new global var) in scala.js `1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you'll always be in a browser context, you can use `@JSGlobal("window")` instead of `@JSGlobalScope` on your `Globals`, which will then be equivalent to doing `window.myGlobalVarFor3rdPartyLib` in JS. So that will work.

```
@js.native
@JSGlobal("window")
object Globals extends js.Object {
  var callbackFunctionFor3rdPartyLib: js.Function0[Unit] = js.native
}
```

---

If not, but you are using a *script* (so not a CommonJS nor an ES module), the best thing is actually to use

```
object Globals {
  @JSExportTopLevel("myGlobalVarFor3rdPartyLib")
  var foo: js.Function[Unit] = ...
}
```

Note that `Globals` is a normal Scala object now, not a JS one.

The `@JSExportTopLevel` creates a top-level `var myGlobalVarFor3rdPartyLib` at the top of the script, and then assigning `Globals.foo` will also assign that top-level `var`.

---

If you're not using a script nor know that you're going to always be in a browser, then you need to figure out the global object yourself. Scala.js 0.6.x tried to do that for you, but could fail, so we don't do that anymore. You can at least follow the "instructions" on [the documentation of `js.special.fileLevelThis`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/508dcf48910102cec222cf5201ca2450e2192da9/library/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/js/special/package.scala#L148-L166) to reproduce what Scala.js 0.6.x was doing. I repeat the instructions here:

> Using this value should be rare, and mostly limited to writing code
>   detecting what the global object is. For example, a typical detection
>   code--in case we do not need to worry of ES modules--looks like:
>
> ```
> val globalObject = {
>   import js.Dynamic.{global => g}
>   if (js.typeOf(g.global) != "undefined" && (g.global.Object eq g.Object)) {
>     // Node.js environment detected
>     g.global
>   } else {
>     // In all other well-known environment, we can use the global `this`
>     js.special.fileLevelThis
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the above code is not comprehensive, as there can be JavaScript
>   environments where the global object cannot be fetched neither through
>   `global` nor `this`. If your code needs to run in such an environment, it
>   is up to you to use an appropriate detection procedure.